# Does indirectly killing NPCs ruin your non-lethal run in Deus Ex Mankind Divided?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

Without spoilers, on a side quest in the first area you can explore (after prologue mission), you can report an NPC to the police, which results in a gun-fight between the NPCs and the Police.

Does indirect killing like this affect non-lethal runs? Specifically actions you take that cause people to get killed by someone else.

Comment: A mod deleted my answer referring to how deaths indirectly caused by the player in DX:HR did **not** cause one to miss the [Pacifist achievement](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Pacifist), so I'm just restating that here.  Unfortunately, the spoiler markup is not available in comments, so I don't want to go into detail about those deaths.

Comment: Worth noting: in DX:HR some indirect deaths did prevent the Pacifist achievement. For example, if you knocked someone out but they subsequently slipped into water and drowned. But I agree with @dg99: assuming Eidos kept the same basic philosophy (which seems likely), one NPC killing another shouldn't cause problems. And assuming they kept the same philosophy, we won't know for sure until someone finds out the hard way by completing the game after having done the experiment: in DX:HR there was no indication mid-game of whether you had blown the Pacifist achievement.

Comment: It would be nice if there was an in-game help menu showing what achievements are still possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Taking actions which result in NPCs dying at the hands of other NPCs does not sacrifice the Pacifist trophy in *Mankind Divided*.  For example, I just received the trophy after a playthrough in which

- > I set the "good" Prague cops on Drahomir and his cronies, resulting in 4 deaths
- > I failed to save Miller's life
- > I accidentally triggered Eliza Cassan's "intervention" in the Red Light District while one of the cops was standing too close to the turret, causing him to die when it exploded
- > I opened a locked gate in the sewers below southern Prague, causing several civilians to be killed by drones
- > I failed to save Koller's life

On the flip side,

- I made sure everyone I knocked unconscious was still marked `Zzz` (rather than dead) after I finished dragging their bodies away.  (A couple times the dragging process killed the person, so I had to reload.)
- I reloaded when a robot that I destroyed blew up too close to a civilian, killing him.